# how to generate hash key by predefine phrase and salt value in IOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, vb.net, cryptography, commoncrypto

I have some .net code to generate hash key for encryption, i want to that code in iOS but i can't found appropriate solution, If anyone have the proper solution please help me

i add the my .net code and it is working fine, i want to convert that code in iOS with same result

```
Public Shared Function Encrypt(ByVal plainText As String) As String

    Dim passPhrase As String = "passPhrase"
    Dim saltValue As String = "saltValue"
    Dim hashAlgorithm As String = "SHA256"

    Dim passwordIterations As Integer = 2
    Dim initVector As String = "abc123def456gh78"
    Dim keySize As Integer = 256

    Dim initVectorBytes As Byte() = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(initVector)
    Dim saltValueBytes As Byte() = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(saltValue)

    Dim plainTextBytes As Byte() = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(plainText)

    Dim password As New PasswordDeriveBytes(passPhrase, saltValueBytes, hashAlgorithm, passwordIterations)
    Dim keyBytes As Byte() = password.GetBytes(keySize \ 8)

End Function
```

Comment: You can use the CommonCrypto framework for SHA256

Comment: @Paulw11 Yes, and FBEncryptorAES class for encryption

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have also facing same issue like this and i found the solution may be it will help full for you.

Get **FBEncryptorAES** library from Github.

Define IV and Key as per your .net algorithms.

Use this method for encrypt and decrypt your text

```
+ (NSData*)encryptData:(NSData*)data
{
    NSData* result = nil;

    // setup output buffer
    size_t bufferSize = [data length] + FBENCRYPT_BLOCK_SIZE;
    void *buffer = malloc(bufferSize);

    // do encrypt
    size_t encryptedSize = 0;
    CCCryptorStatus cryptStatus = CCCrypt(kCCEncrypt,
                                          FBENCRYPT_ALGORITHM,
                                          kCCOptionPKCS7Padding,
                                          cKey,
                                          FBENCRYPT_KEY_SIZE,
                                          cIv,
                                          [data bytes],
                                          [data length],
                                          buffer,
                                          bufferSize,
                                          &encryptedSize);
    if (cryptStatus == kCCSuccess) {
        result = [NSData dataWithBytesNoCopy:buffer length:encryptedSize];
    } else {
        free(buffer);
        NSLog(@"[ERROR] failed to encrypt|CCCryptoStatus: %d", cryptStatus);
    }

    return result;
}

+ (NSData*)decryptData:(NSData*)data
{
    NSData* result = nil;

    // setup output buffer
    size_t bufferSize = [data length] + FBENCRYPT_BLOCK_SIZE;
    void *buffer = malloc(bufferSize);

    // do decrypt
    size_t decryptedSize = 0;
    CCCryptorStatus cryptStatus = CCCrypt(kCCDecrypt,
                                          FBENCRYPT_ALGORITHM,
                                          kCCOptionPKCS7Padding,
                                          cKey,
                                          FBENCRYPT_KEY_SIZE,
                                          cIv,
                                          [data bytes],
                                          [data length],
                                          buffer,
                                          bufferSize,
                                          &decryptedSize);

    if (cryptStatus == kCCSuccess) {
        result = [NSData dataWithBytesNoCopy:buffer length:decryptedSize];
    } else {
        free(buffer);
        NSLog(@"[ERROR] failed to decrypt| CCCryptoStatus: %d", cryptStatus);
    }

    return result;
}
```